How to preserve selected file/files URLs for next use case in Swift in a systemic way?
I am selecting a file with fileImporter and using the URL of file in app. I want somehow preserve or save the URL for next time use, without having to select the file again, therefor I though that bookmark would be a good fit here I am using this funcs for saving and reading bookmarks:
func getAppDocumentDirectory() -> URL? {
    return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
}


func saveBookmark(url: URL, for bookmarkName: String) {
    
    if (url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()) {
        
        defer { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
        
        do {
            
            let bookmarkData = try url.bookmarkData(options: .minimalBookmark, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
            
            if let unwrappedDocumentDirectory: URL = getAppDocumentDirectory() {
                try bookmarkData.write(to: unwrappedDocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(bookmarkName))
                print("Done!")
            }
            
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    }
    else {
        print("Issue with accessing SecurityScopedResource!")
    }
    
}

func readBookmark(for bookmarkName: String, resultURL: (URL) -> Void) {
    
    do {
        
        if let unwrappedDocumentDirectory: URL = getAppDocumentDirectory() {
            
            let bookmarkURL: URL = unwrappedDocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(bookmarkName)
            
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: bookmarkURL.path) {
                
                let bookmarkData = try Data(contentsOf: bookmarkURL)
                var isStale = false
                let url = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
                
                if (!isStale) { resultURL(url) }
                
            }
            else {
                print("There is no such a bookmark exist! with name of:", bookmarkName)
            }
            
        }
        else {
            print("Issue with accessing App documentDirectory!")
        }
        
    }
    catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}

I would have no issue if it was some handful of files let say between 1-5 files, then I could simply use file1, file2, file3, file4, file5 for bookmarkName but the issue is that the amount of selected files could go 50 or 100 or more, so it would be a big issue for me tracking bookmarkNames between 1-200, like file1, file2, file3, ..., file200. it looks like chaos coding for me, the only possible way that I can think write now is saving the amount of selected files by user like 120 files with UserDefaults and then looping 120 times something like this:
func readAll(value: Int) {
    
    for number in 1...value {
        
        readBookmark(for: "file" + String(number), resultURL: { myURL in
            
            print(myURL.lastPathComponent)
            
        })
        
    }
    
}

So my issue is not about saving or reading the bookmarks, the issue is how to keep tracking them in more systematic way?

URL conforms to Codable so one solution could be to write an array of all your URL’s in a json file or use the writeBookmarkData(_:to:) method to write all bookmarks to a specific folder.

If I understand correctly, you just want to get a list of all the saved bookmarks.
Bookmarks are just Data. Each bookmark doesn't have to be written to a different file. For example, you can encode a Data array containing all the bookmarks using a JSONEncoder, and write that into a single file. Then, decoding that would give you all your bookmarks.
Or you can encode a [String: Data] if you want the bookmarks to have names associated with them.
A third option would be to store it as a SwiftData model, like
@Model
class Bookmark {
    var name: String
    var data: Data

    init(name: String, data: Data) {
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
    }
}

You'd then be able to get all of them from the ModelContext, or a @Query.
You can still just store each bookmark as a different file. Store them all in the same directory, and use contentsOfDirectory to retrieve them.
Frankly, this is really no different from persisting any other kind of Data.
